# PaperTrail gem records user as "unknown" from a spun off sidekiq background image processing job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paper-trail-gem

So, paper trail works great as planned, and records changes by current_user, but updating or creating an object with an image returns a new change with "unknown" after running the background image processing job.

Here's an example of the output:

```
25 Mar 2020 | Trey Walls
{"id"=>[nil, 11359], "issue_number"=>[nil, "1"], "variety"=>[nil, "b"], "border_color_id"=>[nil, "67"], "border_type_id"=>[nil, "1"], "background_color_id"=>[nil, "41"], "lettering_color_id"=>[nil, "57"], "fdl_bsa_color_id"=>[nil, ""], "first_issue"=>[nil, Mon, 01 Jan 1962], "description"=>[nil, "Arrowhead on LBR Mountain Top, 2 per Honor Level"], "created_at"=>[nil, Wed, 25 Mar 2020 18:51:06 EDT -04:00], "updated_at"=>[nil, Wed, 25 Mar 2020 18:51:06 EDT -04:00], "issue_type_id"=>[nil, 5], "image"=>[nil, nil], "oa_bb_issue_number"=>[nil, ""], "oa_bb_combined"=>[nil, "unlisted"], "combined"=>[nil, "F1b"], "oa_bb_variety"=>[nil, ""], "category_id"=>[nil, 1], "slug"=>[nil, "f1b"], "patchscan_url"=>[nil, ""], "width"=>[nil, 122], "height"=>[nil, 51], "shortname"=>[nil, ""], "history"=>[nil, ""], "material_id"=>[nil, 3], "backing_type_id"=>[nil, 1], "issue_shape_id"=>[nil, 6], "issueable_id"=>[nil, 844], "issueable_type"=>[nil, "Lodge"], "listed_in_error"=>[nil, false], "uuid"=>[nil, "c+xzIYvbiNk="], "designer"=>[nil, ""], "supress_missing_back_image"=>[nil, false], "date_type"=>["precise", "approximate year"], "image_processing"=>[false, true]}

26 Mar 2020 | Trey Walls
{"designer"=>["", "Robert Summers"], "first_issue"=>[Mon, 01 Jan 1962, Sun, 01 Jan 1961], "image"=>[nil, nil], "updated_at"=>[Wed, 25 Mar 2020 18:51:06 EDT -04:00, Thu, 26 Mar 2020 15:36:14 EDT -04:00]}

26 Mar 2020 | Trey Walls
{"image"=>[nil, "544f1bfront.jpg"], "imageback"=>[nil, "544f1bback_copy.jpg"], "imageback_processing"=>[false, true], "updated_at"=>[Thu, 26 Mar 2020 15:36:14 EDT -04:00, Thu, 26 Mar 2020 15:36:47 EDT -04:00]}

26 Mar 2020 | Unknown User
{"imageback_processing"=>[true, false], "updated_at"=>[Thu, 26 Mar 2020 15:36:47 EDT -04:00, Thu, 26 Mar 2020 15:37:03 EDT -04:00]}

26 Mar 2020 | Unknown User
{"image_processing"=>[true, false], "updated_at"=>[Thu, 26 Mar 2020 15:36:47 EDT -04:00, Thu, 26 Mar 2020 15:37:04 EDT -04:00]}
```

This only happens when a user adds or updates the image on a record, so I'm assuming it's the background job.

Comment: _records changes_ How, exactly? Your log isn't important; seeing the code that shows how it happens is.

Comment: The gem method: `before_action :set_paper_trail_whodunnit` in application_controller.rb. It works for submits, but when the image processing sidekiq task comes back it does not record a user.

Comment: How exactly is an asynchronous job processor that runs separately from your Rails app that runs a worker in isolation supposed to know anything about or do anything with methods in your controller?